# Enable SSH2 for PHP 5.4.7 in windows 7 x86 Environment

Tags: php, windows, ssh, libssh2

Hi guys I am in the need to use ssh2 functionalities in php 5.4.7

My configurations are as follows

```
xampp 1.8.3
php 5.4.7
Compiler - MSVC9 (Visual C++ 2008)
PHP API - 20100412
PHP Extension - 20100525
Zend Extension - 220100525
Zend Extension Build - API220100525,TS,VC9
```

and I have downloaded ssh api from this link [Windows PHP](http://windows.php.net/downloads/pecl/releases/ssh2/0.12/), version name is

```
php_ssh2-0.12-5.4-ts-vc9-x86
```

Extracted the zip file and placed php_ssh2.dll and php_ssh2.pdb in the php extension folder and libssh2.dll into system32 folder, and changed the php.ini to enable the extension and restarted the apache. all is working fine and openssl also enabled

after enabling ssh2

```
Registered PHP Streams - php, file, glob, data, http, ftp, zip, compress.zlib, compress.bzip2, https, ftps, phar, ssh2.shell, ssh2.exec, ssh2.tunnel, ssh2.scp, ssh2.sftp
```

but when I try to connect using ssh2_connect('server.com', 22) it leads to stop the apache server. what I am doing wrong here?